# -exact parameter with custom fields is not working

Tags: solspace, supersearch

I cannot get the -exact parameter to work in a search string using Super Search 2.2.3 and EE 2.9.2.

I have a custom field named doctors_services and I've tried this search query:

```
/search/doctors/search&channel=doctors&doctors_services=Primary%20Care
```

This works - it returns results for Primary Care. **However,** this search also returns other services with "Care" in the name - eg. "Wound Care"

According to the documentation from Solspace (found here: https://solspace.com/docs/super_search/search_syntax/#custom_fields), I should be able to pass an -exact parameter in the string like this:

```
/search/doctors/search&channel=doctors&doctors_services-exact=Primary%20Care
```

**This returns zero results.** Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I feel like this is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my question. You cannot do exact searches on a Playa field: https://solspace.com/docs/super_search/third_party_support/#pt_playa

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with a `+` instead of `%20`? Just in case it's an encoding issue here wit hthe exact syntax?

Your parameters look correct, bear in mind also that exact matches the entire field, not just the text supplied, so if you have leading or training characters (even spaces) the loose search will match, the exact one won't...

Comment: This also returns zero results: /search/doctors/search&channel=doctors&doctors_services-exact=Primary+Care

Comment: BTW - the field in question - doctors_services - is a Playa field. I'm wondering if there's some funky characters in there? There shouldn't be, it should just be the title of the Playa related entry.